# Installing .NET 4.0 Framework on Wine using Winetricks

Tags: .net-framework, ubuntu, wine, xubuntu

I use Xubuntu 12.04 and I installed Wine 1.4. I am now trying to install the .NET 4.0 Framework using Winetricks. I use this command

```
sudo sh winetricks dotnet40
```

But I get this error

```
wine cmd.exe / c echo '% ProgramFiles%' returned empty string
```

I get this error when I try to install other programs as well. I have managed to install .NET Framework 4.0. previously, but now I can not get this install to go smoothly. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You don't need to use sudo there.

Comment: You can find an in-depth tutorial at [ask-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548909/running-net-4-0-application-with-wine)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/548909/running-net-4-0-application-with-wine

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install winetricks
$ winetricks dotnet40
```

To install using gui, you can try `winetricks --gui`, than choose install app, than cancel and in new window, choose install windows part or library. There are dot net dependencies.

To show installed things, you can `winetricks list-installed`.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04. I advise to use the command line, not the gui. Might throw some message boxes, which is annoying.

Answer (score 8):

For a 64bit system you need to make a 32bit prefix and put the dotnet4.0 in it.

So:

`wget http://winetricks.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/winetricks`

Then:

`env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet40`

Comment: `wget http://winetricks.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/winetricks`: `2018-09-24 13:41:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Answer (score 2):

did you get the file first?  Try the following:

> $ ­wget http://winetricks.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/winetricks
>
> $ bash winetricks dotnet40

WineHQ gives .NET 4 a bronze rating at best.  Its ability to install and run properly will vary by which version of Wine you are running.

Comment: The googlecode URL is gone - do we have a replacement? Or do we need one? There's either the Github repo (https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks) or you can try to install it yourself from the distro's repos. It came with my version of `wine` on Ubuntu 16.04.